# How can I secure all traffic using strongSwan/IPSec except SSH access?

Tags: strongswan

how can I configure strongSwan to require IPSec for all connections except *SSH* connections?

I tried creating two connections:

1. Create a "connection" for SSH using passthrough mode (left=%any/right=%any) and leftsubnet=%dynamic[tcp/22]
2. Secure all traffic with transport mode (left=%any/right=%any)

However, when I restart strongSwan, I cannot SSH into the server. It seems to me I have to prioritize the connections, but I have found no way to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jochen